# How to pass nested resource to custom helper for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the code

Model:

Category has many subjects

View:

show:

```
<% category.subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <div class="container">                           
    <%= render partial: "layouts/trial", :locals => {:subject => subject} %>
  </div>                 
<% end %>
```

layouts/trial:

```
<%= description(@subject)  %>
```

trial_helper.rb

```
module TrialHelper
  def subject
    @subject ||= []
  end

  def description(subject)
    @des = "#{subject.content}"
  end

end
```

turn out

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass):
    1:       <%= description(@subject)  %>
```

I've tried using

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/trial", :locals => {:subject => @category.subject} %>
```

and

```
def description(subject)
  @des = "#{@subject.content}"
end
```

But it's still not work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `subject` is `nil` in your `layouts/trial`.

The best approach is to debug and check where the problem is occurring.

You can set in your `layouts/trial` something like `<%= raise @subject.inspect %>` and if it really returns nil, we can confirm that this code here `<%= render partial: "layouts/trial", :locals => {:subject => subject} %>` isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<%= description(@subject)  %>
```

to

```
<%= description(subject)  %>
```

locals are passed as `local variables` not `instance variables`